# Headers in SSRS Reports in Excel

Tags: excel, reporting-services, visual-studio-2005

I'm using VS 2005 to create database reports. In some cases, these reports are viewed in Excel, and quite often, the reports contain many many columns, necessitating multiple pages for a single row when printing.

The way they're behaving in Excel, by default, is as follows:

The header appears at the top of the report, occupying ~5 rows which are locked and do not scroll with the document. Footers do not appear when viewed in Excel.

When printed, the footer appears on each page, but the header appears only once, centred on the 'middle' page (remember that each page is a part of a single row, so that if the pages are placed side by side horizontally, it would reconstruct the table):

[image: sample]

The footers are behaving as desired.

> My question is: How can I make the header behave in the same way, so
> that it appears on each page, instead of only on the 'middle' page?

I need a solution that can be implemented in VS. Doing this manually in Excel is not an option.

Comment: Is this header row all one merged cell when exported to Excel?

Comment: Can you show your rdl design. Is your problem only when printing from excel?

Comment: @Jonnus No. There are multiple merged cells. Some are empty, others contain the Title, another the image in the header, and others for other header info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that Microsoft **ass**u**me**s that you want the header to be part of the records that are shown while the footers are put in the footer section of the Excel sheet so they duplicate when necessary.

There is a **SimplePageHeaders** property in a configuration file that can fix this. Unfortunately, I work in an environment where I can't change the config file - RSReportserver.config.

Here are some instructions if you want to try changing the export to put the header in the Excel Header and Footer section:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sqlserver/en-US/84893b1b-8f41-4fcf-aab9-72d2d5f60544/simplepageheader-property-in-ssrs-2008-not-working

Comment: That article looks like what I want to accomplish. Thanks for the response. 

While I'm waiting for some red tape at the office to be cut before I can modify the file, I was wondering if you can answer a secondary question.

The article says 'Note: Changing the rendering extension parameters only affects rendering operations on the Report Server.'

I'm using Aras' Innovator to pull the reports from ssrs, does this mean I won't see the rendering changes unless I pull directly from ssrs (i.e. not using Innovator?)

Comment: So it looks like I've partially answered my own question (the second part at least). Using the article you provided, with a few tweaks, I was able to have at least the title (which is contained in the header) show up (even when run from Innovator). However, I have an image and some additional textboxes as part of the header, and they are NOT showing up. Any ideas?

Comment: Unfortunately the Excel headers and footers aren't very flexible. They are just 3 cells across the page. I'm guessing whatever doesn't easily fit into the format gets ignored. You can check this out but I don't see anything that would help: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220421(v=sql.110).aspx